# Tricky condition in query

Tags: mysql

I am working on a college project and I am pretty stuck on these query.Our database looks like these:

```
passengers(id,year_of_birth,name,surname)
flights_has_passengers(flights_id,passengers_id)
flights(id,routes_id,date)
routes(id,airlines_id)
airlines(id,name,alias,country,code,active)
```

We have been asked to find the passengers who have travelled ONLY with the airline company named 'British Airways'.My code so far is:

```
SELECT passengers.name,passengers.surname 
FROM passengers
INNER JOIN flights_has_passengers on flights_has_passengers.passengers_id=passengers.id
INNER JOIN flights on flights_has_passengers.flights_id=flights.id
INNER JOIN routes on routes.id=flights.routes_id
INNER JOINairlines on routes.airlines_id=airlines.id
WHERE airlines.name='British Airways'
HAVING 
count(airlines.name)
ORDER BY passengers.name,passengers.surname
```

This code finds the passengers who have travelled with British Airway,but also they have travelled with other companies.So my question is how do I get the passengers who have travelled ONLY with British Airways.

PS:Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try asserting in the `HAVING` clause that no airlines other than British Airways appears:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.surname 
FROM passengers p
INNER JOIN flights_has_passengers fhp
    ON fhp.passengers_id = p.id
INNER JOIN flights f
    ON fhp.flights_id = f.id
INNER JOIN routes r
    ON r.id = f.routes_id
INNER JOIN airlines a
    ON r.airlines_id = a.id
GROUP BY
    p.name,
    p.surname 
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.name <> 'British Airways' THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY
    p.name,
    p.surname;
```

Note that I introduced table aliases into the query, making it easier to read.

Comment: yeah sorry for the form of the code.Thanks for the help!